# Is it legal to construct data members of a struct separately?

Tags: c++, struct, language-lawyer, c++98, placement-new

```
class A;
class B;
//we have void *p pointing to enough free memory initially
std::pair<A,B> *pp=static_cast<std::pair<A,B> *>(p);
new (&pp->first) A(/*...*/);
new (&pp->second) B(/*...*/);
```

After the code above get executed, is `*pp` guaranteed to be in a valid state? I know the answer is true for every compiler I have tested, but the question is whether this is legal according to the standard and hence. In addition, is there any other way to obtain such a `pair` if `A` or `B` is not movable in C++98/03? (thanks to @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica , there is a piecewise constructor for `std::pair` since C++11)

Comment: Hmm. Piecewise placement new. I bet it's underspecified; this stuff usually is. But my question to you is.... _why_??? Why do you think you need to do this? If you have to ask whether a construct is legal, you shouldn't be using it, for lack of clarity if nothing else (but there is so much else)

Comment: I'm assuming `A` and `B` are full types, right?

Comment: Hmm, `std::pair` has a constructor that does exactly this (piecewise construction). So yeah, why?

Comment: @Chipster yes, they're full types

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Not _exactly_ this; the pair itself is being properly constructed by the said-same constructor. Not so in the OP's example. The parent object remains non-existent from the object model's perspective. That's the question.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica - Yes of course. I meant the supposed goal by "this", minus the foot being potentially shot off.

Comment: @StoryTeller Although I used `auto` in the code, the question can also be asked for C++ 98.

Comment: @Lightness just for curiosity

Comment: @user - Considering the object model has gone through some turmoil from publication to publication, you can't really ask this as far back as C++98 without qualifying by standard. So which is it?

Comment: @StoryTeller Let's say it is C++98.

Comment: Okay. I added the relevant tags then. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @StoryTeller of course not.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica: Is it a memory leak?

Comment: @Itachi Assume I take good care of memory.

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa No

Comment: I may look into this if it gets _really_ rainy outside, but I'm afraid it's probably not worth the insubstantial effort it'll require, given that you don't actually face any practical problem and are merely curious.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica: You mean that `pp` will free the memory later on?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa I mean that the OP didn't show the allocation code, so it's fair that they also did not show the deallocation code. I'm not saying there is not necessarily a memory leak in the program, but I don't believe that the question indicates one. And, even if it did, that would still be pretty tangential to what is being asked.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica "_object model has gone through some turmoil_" Yes but it's still so broken 1) you can't use string literals and 2) now it even refers to objects that will be there, which means the C++ semantic is not step by step, not even w/o threads.

Comment: What is guaranteed by the std about `std::pair`? Couldn't it be a polymorphic class? (For no imaginable reason.)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica: I didn't understand this: `new (&pp->first) A(/*...*/);`

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa It's called _placement new_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“Accessing” the members of the non-existent `pair` object is undefined behavior per [basic.life]/5; `pair` is never a POD-class (having user-declared constructors), so a pointer to its storage out of lifetime may not be used for its members.  It’s not clear whether forming a pointer to the member is already undefined, or if the `new` is.

Neither is there a way to construct a pair of non-copyable (not *movable*, of course) types in C++98—that’s why the piecewise constructor was added *along with* move semantics.

Answer (score -2):

A more simple question: is using a literal string well defined?

Not even that is, as its lifetime is not defined. You can't use a string literal in conforming code.

So the committee that never took the time to make string literals well defined obviously did not bother with specifying *which* objects of class type can be made to exist by placement new of its subobjects - polymorphic objects obviously cannot be created that way!

**That standard did not even bother describing the semantic of union.**

About lifetime the standard is all over the place, and that isn't just editorial: it reflects a deep disagreement between serious people about what begins a lifetime, what an object is, what an lvalue is, etc.

Notably people have all sorts of false or contradicting intuitions:

- an infinite number of objects cannot be created by one call to `malloc`
- an lvalue refers to an object
- overlapping objects are against the object model
- a unnamed object can only be created by `new` or by the compiler (temporaries)
  ...

Comment: The semantics of `union` _are_ described. They're just not what a bunch of people mistakenly think they are.

Comment: And I have no idea what you're going on about with regards to string literals

Comment: Objects are regions of storage ([ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#1)), and literals are not that. However, in case you're concerned about dereferencing etc: _"Evaluating a string-literal results in a string literal object with static storage duration"_ ([ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#15)) & then the usual rules apply

Comment: Anyway, this does not even attempt to address the question that was written.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica When is a string literal created? "_then the usual rules apply_" Which rules?

Comment: "_this does not even attempt to address the question that was written_" It does. It proves that very simple stuff is not properly covered so the Q is vain. When simple stuff isn't covered, very strange stuff will not be.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica "_The semantics of union are described_" No it isn't. Also, notice past tense.

Comment: The question is tagged for C++98, but note that the “deep disagreement” issues are in fact being resolved: [P0593](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p0593r4.html) is handling the “infinite number of objects”, and [P1971](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1971r0.html) (to be posted there in a few weeks) is one of several object model refinements.